# How to validate whether SQL server 2008 was busy (not responding) at some point of time during the day

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, event-viewer

I am part of UI team and we have developed a asp.net mvc application which uses SQL server as the backend. Every time SQL server becomes busy, the application stops responding. I saw the event logs and following entry was made on the application server.

```
System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. 
See the inner exception for details. ---> 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. 
The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or 
the server is not    responding
```

But by the time DB team start looking into the issue the DB server becomes responsive and there is no solid way to tell error was caused due to SQL server. Is there any way to check some log on SQL server and say server was busy/not responding at any specific period of time.

Comment: This sounds more like a deadlock than "server busy".

Comment: Blocking. Not deadlock. Deadlock would return a different error. You might want to configure the blocked process report. Probably some open transaction is holding locks open too long.

Comment: @MartinSmith: How can i configure blocked process report?

Comment: @Brown_Dynamite - Google it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
exec xp_readerrorlog
```

Also doublecheck what DB you use in your connection string. You can get this type of error just because the DB is offline.